# when I boot via the installation media, it says "checking disks" and then turns off

Tags: software-installation

I put the installation files onto my USB, first by using WinRAR. When I booted via the installation drive, it would boot into grub, but then when it tried to run Ubuntu, it said "checking disks" and then my laptop would turn off.
I then tried using rufus to put the files onto the USB, it got a little further, the progress bar now gets to 10% when it checks disks, but it still turns off when it gets to there.

Comment: just putting the files on the drive is not making a bootable usb follow this link(https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview)

Comment: To add the the above, I've had great results with [Balena Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) lately. It is pretty speedy and I've yet to have any fail on me.

Comment: You need to verify the downloaded file to make sure it isn't corrupted: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview.

Comment: @wraith2390 001 I did use Rufus after using WinRAR wasn't working, I followed that tutorial, it's not working

Comment: The Ubuntu installer does not "turn off" your laptop for any reason. You laptop's hardware, however, might turn *itself* off for many possible reasons: Overheating and faulty power supply are the two most common. These usually indicate a hardware fault of some kind: Obstructed airflow, broken fan, faulty power connector, dying battery, and many others. None are Ubuntu-related, though they are often *coincidentallly* exposed by the stress and power requirements of a new install.

Comment: @user535733 my laptop boots into windows just fine, it has never shut itself off unless I told it to while using windows. When I try to run the installation drive, though, it boots into grub and starts ubuntu; but then when it scans disks, it shuts off.

Comment: You either have a faulty .iso image, a faulty USB creation from that image, or faulty hardware. A, B or C. The 20.04 installer checks it's own hash ("integrity check")  at boot to rule out A. That leaves you to rule out B or C. Try the USB on different hardware.

Comment: @user535733 I don't have different hardware to try it on, the USB was in perfect working order when I started. Also, since when I last replied, I had a friend try to help me and they completely botched my USB, so I don't know what to do now

Comment: Try that USB on the friend's machine. Seems like they owe you a favor. If you are careful about reading the prompts, you won't erase their OS.

Comment: @user535733 that friend lives on the opposite side of the continent from me, he was helping me over an instant messaging app. also, just realised that there's some text that explain what's probably happening, I just didn't realise they were errors until just now, is there some way I can upload a picture of them? another thing I guess I should add to this, I said they botched it, which they did, but it still has the installation files on it, it's just partitioned in a way that I can't revert it back to its original partitions.

Comment: I've figured out it was UEFI secure boot